# Error using Query Parameters with cfscript query

Tags: coldfusion

Here is my code:

```
var qryStr = "
            UPDATE templates_email 
            SET title = :title, test_emails = :testEmail, body = :body
            WHERE id = :templateID";

q = New Query();
q.setSQL(qryStr);
q.addParam(name="title", value="#arguments.title#", cfsqltype="cf_sql_char");
q.addParam(name="body", value="#arguments.templateContent#", cfsqltype="cf_sql_char");
q.addParam(name="testEmail", value="#arguments.test_emails#", cfsqltype="cf_sql_char");
q.addParam(name="templateID", value="#arguments.id#", cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer");

return q.execute().getResult();
```

This is the error:

> Parameter 'body WHERE' not found in the list of parameters specified
>
> SQL: UPDATE templates_email SET title = :title, test_emails = :testEmail, body = :body WHERE id = :templateID
>
> The error occurred in C:\ColdFusion9\CustomTags\com\adobe\coldfusion\query.cfc: line 108

I can only assume I have done something wrong with the way my SQL is structured with the parameters, but can't work out what it is. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried switching around the order of the columns, so that "body" is not the last one?  If so, did you get a similar error, but this time with the new, last column?

Comment: Hi Jake..yes, tried that, and did get the same error on the column that had been placed at the end.  Marks explanation below explains very accurately what the problem was.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The parser for getting the params doesn't tokenize on return values, only on whitespace (which is really annoying). Try the following:

```
var qryStr = "
    UPDATE templates_email 
    SET title = ( :title ), test_emails = ( :testEmail ), body = ( :body )
    WHERE ( id = :templateID )
";
```

The `(` and `)` should remove any issue with where the parser not being able to recognise where the :params stop and start.

Comment: Spot on! Thanks Mark! Appreciated.

Comment: I originally missed the fact that you have spaces between the parentheses and the parameters - these are important, without them, it doesn't work. Generous spaces FTW :)

Comment: Your explanation is a little misleading. The problem is that it doesn't tokenize on *whitespace*, it tokenizes on *space*. It considers tab and newline to be part of the param names. Adding a single space character after the param name (without even using the parens) will also fix it. That said, the paren is better because someone's editor might be set to remove trailing whitespace when they touch a file.

Answer (score 6):

This error occurs because of the tab and line break characters found in your SQL statement. I normally run below function on my SQL statement to remove these characters.

```
string function cleanSQL(required string sqlStatement)
    output="false"
{
return trim(reReplace(arguments.sqlStatement, "\t|\n", " ", "all"));
}
```

So, your setSQL() can look like:

```
q.setSQL(cleanSQL(qryStr))
```

or simply:

```
q.setSQL(reReplace(qryStr, "\t|\n", " ", "all"))
```

Answer (score 0):

ColdFusion can get confused when parsing the SQL string to use parameters. The easiest way to solve this shortcoming is to put a space after each of your parameters.

Since some text editors may remove trailing whitespace, like when saving, I include an empty comment after any space at the end of a line.

```
var qryStr = "
    UPDATE templates_email 
    SET title = :title , test_emails = :testEmail , body = :body /**/
    WHERE id = :templateID /**/
";
```