# Coldfusion error executing a sql statement

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I keep getting a error that says,

> Argument 2 of function Replace cannot be an empty

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

The code:

```
local.drafts.setSQL( "INSERT messages (tm, draft, linkA, linkB) values (:tm:, :draft:, :linkA:, :linkB:");
local.drafts.addParam(name="tm",value=s,CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_TIMESTAMP");
local.drafts.addParam(name="draft",value=1, CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_BIT");
local.drafts.addParam(name="linkA",value=h,CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_SMALLINT");
local.drafts.addParam(name="linkB",value=b,CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_SMALLINT");    
local.drafts.execute();
```

Comment: do you have a function called `replace()` somewhere before this code? That's my first guess.

Comment: Do you have an insert trigger that might be failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like an issue with Mura's Search Engine Safe (SES) URLs.

This is a replace function error see hasbro's example!
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:a0Dxwwp5iPsJ:www.hasbro.com/games/en_US/clue/virtual-mansion/fileSizes.cfm%3Ffn0%3D%26fn1%3Dclue.swf%26&hl=en&gl=us&strip=1

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure the syntax is correct? I don't recall the ending : so would try (keeping note of trailing spaces)

```
local.drafts.setSQL("INSERT INTO messages (tm, draft, linkA, linkB) VALUES ( :tm , :draft , :linkA , :linkB )");
```

Might just be that your trailing bracket on the VALUES is on the wrong side of a quote of course

Similar issue was seen in this [Error using Query Parameters with cfscript query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8426044/1213554)

If of course this is due to a C+P error please re-post source

Comment: Correct, only leading colon for query params. eg. `:param`.

Comment: There is also a bug in the CF query sql parser that means we MUST have a leading and trailing space around each `:param`. Same goes for positional params. eg. `?`. CR/LF and TAB will not do - it must be a space either side! Lame...