# Strange query string behavior

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

CF allow the query string to be on multiple lines. So I had my query string stored in a variable in multiple lines like

```
var strSQL="select
a.col1,
a.col2,
b.col3,
b.col4,
CASE WHEN Some_XYZ>0.1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as kStatus
FROM (A_Derived_Table)
";
```

This is a part of REST API and query either will take too long or just times out (api service does not return results). I have many other queries written in same manner for sake of readability and never had any issue with them. 
In sql server same query runs under a second.
When I modified API and returned back the generated sql, I noticed lot of \t (tab) being added to sql string. I changed the string to

```
var strSQL="select a.col1, a.col2, b.col3, b.col4, CASE WHEN Some_XYZ>0.1 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as kStatus FROM (A_Derived_Table)";
```

and everything started working well.
What/why is this behavior? Environment CF10, SQL server 2008 on IIS7

Comment: White space shouldn't affect the query performance. Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12021114/923833) to a simmulare question.

Comment: I believe that is a known issue/limitation with writing queries in cfscript - [Tip using ColdFusion query in cfscript and something to watch out for](http://www.andyscott.id.au/blog/tip-using-coldfusion-query-in-cfscript-and-something-to-watch-out-for) and this similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/8426044/1636917. There is also a mention of it here - [Learning ColdFusion 9: Using CFQuery (And Other Service Tags) In CFScript](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1678-learning-coldfusion-9-using-cfquery-and-other-service-tags-in-cfscript.htm)

Comment: @Miguel-F, thanks. So my shot in the dark, moving them in a single line made it working, was due to this known limitation. I played a bit and found that this behavior is more evident when I copy the query from say management studio and put it in string variable, rather than typing directly inside the editor in variable content. Can you post this as answer. SO question you mentioned is similar but with different cause and different symptoms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*From the comments*

I believe that is a known issue/limitation with writing queries in cfscript - [Tip using ColdFusion query in cfscript and something to watch out for](http://www.andyscott.id.au/blog/tip-using-coldfusion-query-in-cfscript-and-something-to-watch-out-for) and this similar question - [Error using Query Paramaters with cfscript query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8426044/1636917). There is also a mention of it here - [Learning ColdFusion 9: Using CFQuery (And Other Service Tags) In CFScript](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1678-learning-coldfusion-9-using-cfquery-and-other-service-tags-in-cfscript.htm)